# Start a call to phone and close after n seconds android

Tags: android, user-interface

i want to develop an application that call an gsm tool that open my home gate. I' need to start a call from an android application to my gate number, and after 3/4 seconds close it.

It's possible?

Also the best way that i can develop my app, is to mask the call with no viewing the standard calling ui, with buttons like close,speakers..etc during the call.

It would be nice to clicking the "open gate" button and remaining to the app interface.

Thanks